# Is there a clean way to map specific exception types to a validation failure style ProblemDetails?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, validation, .net-core, error-handling

With `AddProblemDetails()` exception handling enabled in ASP.NET Core, the default behaviour is to return a HTTP 500 with `ProblemDetails` upon handling a thrown exception. Are there any provisions to specify certain exceptions return a validation failure style problem details i.e HTTP 400 with an array of errors instead of the default server error 500?

There is

```
builder.Services.AddProblemDetails(opt => opt.CustomizeProblemDetails = ..);
```

but this allow me to modify the already created `ProblemDetails`. I can overwrite the values to that of a validation failure (i.e set the status code to 400) but this seems kinda clunky as I need to alter a few fields and seemingly can't add to the errors collection with my validation failure info pulled from the exception.

It seems like maybe I'm missing somewhere to hook into and override the actual creation of the `ProblemDetails` on exception.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried as below,is it what you want?

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post(string Path)
        {
           
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }
```

in program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddProblemDetails(x =>
{
    x.CustomizeProblemDetails = ctx =>
    {
        var exception = ctx.HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>()?.Error;
        if(exception != null&&exception is FileNotFoundException)
        {
            ctx.ProblemDetails.Status = 400;
            ctx.ProblemDetails.Detail=exception.Message;
            ctx.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;
        }
        if(exception != null&& exception is ArgumentNullException)
        {
            ctx.ProblemDetails.Title = "Null exception";
            ctx.ProblemDetails.Detail = exception.Message;
            ctx.ProblemDetails.Status = 409;
          
        }
        ......
    };
});

var app = builder.Build();


app.UseExceptionHandler();
```

Result:

[image]

Related [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0#problem-details-from-middleware)

Comment: That's not an exception, that's a validation failure because of the `[Required]` attribute on `Summary`.

Comment: I've updated my answer,is it what you want ?

Comment: I checked the document  ,blogs and source codes related  with the middleware and  found a solution  better , and updated it ,hopes help

Comment: Yes, that works. What I ended up doing in the end was creating an interface with a function like `UpdateProblemDetails` for my exceptions and then adding some code in `CustomizeProblemDetails` that calls this method to make exception specific changes to the ProblemDetails. This helps to keep the mapping between exception and ProblemDetails in the exception class itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in .net 6 then CustomizeProblemDetails isn't an option as far as I can see, but you can edit the ProblemDetails object right before render like this:

```cs
setup.IncludeExceptionDetails = (ctx, env) => true; // Always enable all details otherwise the details value is empty
setup.OnBeforeWriteDetails = (ctx, details) =>
{
    // In production get rid of the extended information such as exception details
    if (builder.Environment.IsProduction())
    {
        foreach (var key in details.Extensions.Keys)
        {
            if (key != "traceId")
            {
                details.Extensions.Remove(key);
            }
        };
    }
};
```

This something I did so I could still have human readable "details" information but not all the stack trace etc in production